Can I somehow advertise the BIU winter school on cryptography?
I organize a winter school on cryptography at Bar-Ilan University in Israel every year (this is the 6th year running; see here). The school studies topics in depth and is meant for people with significant crypto background. It occurred to me that there are people here that may be interested (especially the active members). Is there someway of letting them know about it. (Note that the school is for free; participants just have to pay their travel. In fact, it costs me for every person that comes. So, I have no personal interest here; just community service.)

You could create a post at Community Promotion Ads - 2015, but it might be difficult to get the 6 upvotes required to activate it.

Close to the 6 up votes. 4 at the moment. Only two more.

I actually suggested the Winter School in chat in response to a question there on what we should advertise. 
Community promotion ads are the way to go. Here is an answer with an image that everyone can vote for!
Unfortunately I've never been able to attend one of the BIU winter schools on cryptography, but I have watched a number of the videos. They are fantastic. Really helped me in my PhD work.

Thanks; I'll give it a try. I'm also really happy to hear that the videos helped!

Feel like an idiot. I have no idea how to create an image like I need to and no idea how to upload it to "imgur" (which I've never heard of).

The answer user interface will do the uploading for you. In the text editor, just click on the icon that looks like a landscape (mountain peaks with a circle in the top right corner). That will let you upload it. It says the image must be 220 x 250 pixels. For stuff like that I usually use the open source Gimp program.

I pinged e-sushi in chat to see if he wants to give it a stab. He is one of the more prolific image creators I know of on this site :)

Thanks; much appreciated. (I'm going offline now for a day or two, so I'll check in on the status when I'm back.)

@YehudaLindell No worries… I’ll put something together. Might take a bit though – wife expects me for lunch. I‘ll post another comment when done (probably an hour or two from now).

@YehudaLindell Gotta love my wife… I could squeeze in a few minutes. Is this “ad” OK for you?

Fantastic. Thank you so much (and your wife)!!!!

@YehudaLindell It would be great if you could "accept" this answer (by clicking the checkmark) so that the system (and its users) know the question has been (let’s just call it) “solved”. Thank you in advance. Oh, btw.: noticed Dyadicsec and I have to say I really like the idea behind it. In the unlikely case you ever happen to find yourself looking for “that one, next employee” but can’t find an appropriate one…

Thanks e-sushi! Much appreciated.
